# Swift coding generate random number and link to image and sound

Tags: xcode, swift

I am very new to both programming and swift (please be kind!). I have a working example of how to generate a random image (by assigning a number and using Int(arc4random_uniform(x)). However I do not know how I can say if this image is shown, then assign this sound to the button. Every time an image is displayed it will have a matching sound to go with it. With my limited experience I can only think of doing long winded if statements?

Comment: Write a long winded if statement.  Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Pass the name of the image to a `NSMutableString`, without the extension (.png, or just remove the extension.). Then (hopefully the audio file has the same name as the images name) you can now call the audio file with from the `mutableString`.

---

**Explanation**

For Example. If you have an image named `Dog.png`. Name your audio file that goes with the dog image: `dog.mp3`. (`.mp3` is an example). When the user selects the `dog` image, pass the name to a `muatableString`. Lets call the `mutableString` name `selectedImage`.

Right now, `selectedImage` should have a value of `.png`. (Or whatever extension you have.) Remove the last 3 letters of `selectedImage` like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/deleteCharactersInRange:):

```
func deleteCharactersInRange(_ aRange: NSRange)
```

Next you want to call the audio file using `selectedImage`, and add the extension name like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString:):

```
func appendString(_ aString: String)
```

So `selectedImage`'s value should now be: `dog.mp3`. And you can now call the audio file with `selectedImgae`.

Hope this helps!!

**Edit**

Here is code to play audio files:

var player : AVAudioPlayer! = nil // will be Optional, must supply initializer

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audioFile", ofType:"m4a")
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
player.prepareToPlay()
player.delegate = self
player.play()
```

Comment: Hi, I do understand what you are saying and this would work well however I need assistance in how to call the dog.mp3 audio file. I am sorry if this is ridiculously simple however I am just learning.